# output of [31m text instead of color

Tags: python, terminal, ansi-colors

I am trying to print coloured text with colorama but when I compile an exe and run following...

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print(Fore.RED + 'text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
I get output of::
```

Output:

```
[31mtext
[0m
back to normal now
```

Is it possible to print colors when compiling to pyinstaller exe or is this simply not possible?

Comment: Something is dropping or ignoring the escape character, but you need to tell us more about how you are running this to allow us to figure out why that's happening.  For a start, which version of `colorama`, installed how, on which platform?

Comment: @tripleee I'm using windows and most recent version of colorama. I simply use: Pyinstaller -F color.py

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On Windows, you have to initialize Colorama with `colorama.init()` (see the second line):

```py
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
init()
print(Fore.RED + 'text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

I have tested this code in `cmd` and `PowerShell` and it produces the expected colored output.

From [Colorama docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama#initialisation):

> On Windows, calling `init()` will filter ANSI escape sequences out of any text sent to `stdout` or `stderr`, and replace them with equivalent Win32 calls.
>
> On other platforms, calling `init()` has no effect (unless you request other optional functionality; see “Init Keyword Args”, below). By design, this permits applications to call `init()` unconditionally on all platforms, after which ANSI output should just work.

Answer (score 3):

cmd.exe of Windows doesn't support ANSI escape sequences.

This topic on superuser might helps if you want these be intepreted by cmd.exe natively 
http://superuser.com/questions/413073/windows-console-with-ansi-colors-handling/

So pure crayons might not works under cmd.exe of Windows.

However according to the documentation of colorama

**This has the upshot of providing a simple cross-platform API for printing colored terminal text from Python, and has the happy side-effect that existing applications or libraries which use ANSI sequences to produce colored output on Linux or Macs can now also work on Windows, simply by calling colorama.init().**

Try using [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io). You might be able to do it

Comment: Can this print colored text that would also work if I ran it on my laptop?  Could you provide an example?  Sounds interesting.

Comment: I haven't tested it on windows. If not conemu, there are other packages

Comment: I see.  I assume this would make the colors work on my pc, but if I used this on another external dependency would need to be installed which is not really ideal.

Comment: If you are using it for production level software it's little not appropriate, as you need to add it as external dependency. For stand alone, it seems to be a good idea