# Strange output to console flask server

Tags: python, flask

I was pull my project on another PC and start flask server. Now for everyone requst for server I have strange output like this:

```
[19/Feb/2020 15:54:49] "?[31m?[1mPOST /api/auth HTTP/1.1?[0m" 401 -
```

I mean this symbols like *'?[31m'*. What is this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [output of \[31m text instead of color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432418/output-of-31m-text-instead-of-color)

Comment: They look like color code escape sequences.

Comment: Use a better command line emulator

Comment: No, i didn't work with color. This symbols appeared im pyCharm 2019.2 I'm not sure that this trouble associated with colors.

Answer (score 0):

They are accessing your program using https:// other than http:// . Allow access for https:// or make the default redirect to http://